# pythonの属性に、属性名を格納した文字列の変数を使って参照する方法

Tags: python

pythonの属性に、属性名を格納した文字列の変数を使って参照する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

例えばmodelというオブジェクトに、属性名backbone.body.conv1を格納した文字列

```
x="backbone"
y="body"
z="conv1"
```

で、`model.x.y.z`のように参照して、データを`nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7))`から`nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3))`に書き換えたいと考えております。
現在は下記のコードのようにexec関数を使っておりますが、この関数を使う以外の方法でアクセスする方法はありますでしょうか。

```py
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn


model = torchvision.models.detection.__dict__["maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn"](num_classes=81, pretrained=False)

# 書き換え前の状態を確認
print("model.backbone.body.conv1:", model.backbone.body.conv1)
# model.backbone.body.conv1: Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)

# exec()関数で書き換え
x="backbone"
y="body"
z="conv1"
module="model.{}.{}.{} = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3))".format(x,y,z)
exec(module)

# 書き換え後の状態を確認
print("model.backbone.body.conv1:", model.backbone.body.conv1)
# model.backbone.body.conv1: Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
```

もし対処方法をご存知でしたら教えていただければ幸いです。何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[\[Python\] インスタンスのプロパティへ動的にアクセスする](https://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20161002), [Python超入門その２２〜属性を動的に操作してみよう〜](https://programming-study.com/technology/python-attributes-dynamically/), [オブジェクトの属性を操る(1) - 属性へのアクセス](http://ichitcltk.hustle.ne.jp/gudon2/index.php?pageType=file&id=python_class_attr1.md), [Python のアトリビュート取り扱いの仕組み](https://www.lifewithpython.com/2018/09/python-attribute-access-internal-flow.html)

Comment: @kunif 
様 いつもありがとうございます。返信がかなり遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。紹介いただいたサイトを拝見させていただいたところ、getattrという組み込み関数を下記のように使うことで私のやりたいことが無事に実行できました！ ```print(getattr(getattr(getattr(model, x), y), z))``` 大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問のコメント欄で紹介いただいたサイト（[[Python] インスタンスのプロパティへ動的にアクセスする](https://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20161002) ）を参考に解決できましたので、自己回答させていただきます。

pythonの組み込み関数のgetattr()を使うと、インスタンスのプロパティにアクセスできます。
下記のように多重に使うことで無事に実行できました。

```py
print(getattr(getattr(getattr(model, x), y), z))
```

Answer (score -1):

execの代わりにevalを使うのはいかがでしょう

```py
s = """"model.{}.{}.{} = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3))".format(x,y,z)"""
eval(s)
print("model.backbone.body.conv1:", model.backbone.body.conv1)
```

execの場合と同じ結果になりました。

```
model.backbone.body.conv1: Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
```

---

どうしてexec以外の実現方法を探しているのかを質問に明示した方がよいと思います。
その内容によりますが、execの問題はevalでもだめなような気がします。

Comment: akira ejiri様 ご回答いただきありがとうございます。返信がとても遅くなってしまい、大変申し訳ございませんでした。execとevalはセキュリティリスクがある(Qiitaの記事ですがご参考: https://qiita.com/tkmz/items/717d524083b71a4af75f 　)ようなので、できるだけ使用を控えたいという背景がありました。仰る通り、質問時にそのことを明記しておくべきでした。せっかく実際に検証していただいたのに申し訳ございません。